# Intern: Execute HelperFunction for after every single functional Test

Tags: testing, dojo, intern

I'm currently trying to execute a specific helperFunction after every testcase.

The problem with the beforeEach Function is, that the test is already flagged as successfully/passed (TestLifeCycle already finished).

Is their any configuration possibility to execute a helper Function after every testcase, without pasting it in every single test case?

I'm using the Intern Testframework with the BDD Testinterface.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the BDD interface used for Intern tests are here:

https://theintern.io/docs.html#Intern/4/api/lib%2Finterfaces%2Fbdd

You can use the `afterEach()` method to execute whatever you like once each test in your suite has finished.